# Redesign of Battleship game

Tags: ruby

I created a battlefield with a 10x10 grid. The vertical and horizontal elements have values from 0-9.

The computer has five ships and I want the computer to randomly place each of the five ships in the grid.

The number of blocks each ship occupies is denoted by their numbers in the code below

```
SHIP_HASH = Hash["submarine", 2, "destroyer", 3, "destroyer", 3, "cruiser", 4, "aircraft carrier", 5]
```

The board layout:

```
def board_layout
  board_layout = Array.new(10, " ").map!{|row| Array.new(10, " ")}
  row_label = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
  column_label = [" ", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
  board_layout.unshift(row_label)
  board_layout.each_with_index do |row, i|
    row.unshift(column_label[i])
end
```

end

Is this the way that it should be done? Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Slow down a bit. It is not really possible to get help from someone here to debug your 200 line script. Start with your goal 1, put your input and error message code into the question, and explain in more detail what you mean by "not working".

Comment: You're right. I'm just a little too frustrated that it's not working that's all. @NeilSlater

Comment: btw I would use `SHIP_HASH = { submarine: 2, destroyer: 3, ... }` an easier, more readable way to initialize a hash. Same with arrays: `[10, " "]` is the same as `Array.new(10, " ")`

Comment: If your code works, then asking if there is a simpler way to do it instantly puts your question off-topic for Stack Overflow, and on-topic for [codereview.se].

Comment: Ruby is an object-oriented language. Not array-oriented, not hash-oriented, not string-oriented. I don't see a single object in your code! (Well, numbers, strings, arrays and hashes are objects, but you know what I mean.)

Comment: Also, the indentation is horrible, as are some of the names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SHIP_HASH = { submarine: 2, destroyer: 3, destroyer: 3, cruiser: 4, aircraftcarrier: 5,}

def print_results
 board_layout = Array.new(10, ".").map{|row| Array.new(10, ".")}
 row_label = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
 column_label = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]

print "\t"
print row_label.join("\t")
puts
board_layout.each_with_index do |row, i|
  print column_label[i]
  print "\t"
  print row.join("\t")
  puts
 end
end

print_results
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider these ways of doing what you've written:

This:

```
board_layout = Array.new(10, " ").map{|row| Array.new(10, " ")}
# => [[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
#     [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
#     [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
#     [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
#     [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
#     [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
#     [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
#     [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
#     [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
#     [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]]
```

Or this:

```
board_layout = [[' '] * 10] * 10
# => [[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
#     [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
#     [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
#     [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
#     [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
#     [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
#     [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
#     [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
#     [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
#     [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]]
```

This:

```
row_label = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
# => ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
```

Or one of these:

```
row_label = ('0'..'9').to_a # => ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
row_label = [*('0'..'9')]   # => ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
```

This:

```
column_label = [" ", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
# => [" ", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
```

Or this:

```
column_label = [" ", *('0' .. '9')] # => [" ", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
```

Or even:

```
column_label = [" ", *row_label] # => [" ", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
```

You can do the last one because it's a symmetrical grid.

Comment: Do I need to use a a set of `def` and `end` function in order to execute them? @the

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. I'd suggest working with this for a bit and see if it makes more sense. If it doesn't, then ask a new question that is specific to the problem you've found at that point.

Comment: Good! One of the most important characteristics of a good programmer is that they try, sometimes harder than other times, to figure something out on their own. We're constantly called upon to invent, to create new things from nothing, and that takes inventiveness, logic, and a do-or-die attitude (that also knows when to go ask for help).